How to override react native - expo router header?
In my react native app I am using expo router to navigate between screens. And I am struggling to override the header. Can somebody refer me to the doc if possible, as expo.dev doesn't have enough details.
Let's create a short example using expo: npx create-expo-app expo-router-stack-test
and two files:
/app/details-page/index.tsx
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Yay details page</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

and /app/details-page/_layout.tsx
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function DetailsLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack
      screenOptions={{
        // Hide the header for all other routes.
        //headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          title: "change the title",
          // header: () => null, // hides '<- index' header
        }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}


In our /app/(tabs)/index.tsx let's add a button to navigate to our screen:
      <ThemedView style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Link href="/details-page" asChild>
          <Pressable>
            <Text>Go To details page</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </Link>
        <ThemedText type="title">Welcome!</ThemedText>
        <HelloWave />
      </ThemedView>


in the code above I can modify the second header, while I am looking for a way to override top title as well.

Found a duplicate question here
If someone comes across, for complete answer, you need to update RootLayout- /app/_layout.tsx with:
      <Stack
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >



oh no xD haha, header: () => null (the code you shared) it's supposed to be use for replace or "override" the header for the one you choose, and your "solution" is repeat your header in every layout, it's a bad practice, and it depends of the needings but i bet header its wrong on layout. it should be passed on header: () => <CustomHeader/>
